# Dockerized flask not working in conjunction with dockerized neo4j

Tags: docker, flask, neo4j, docker-compose

I'm trying to run neo4j in one container, and a flask app in another. I have a `docker.compose.yml` like so:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app1:
    container_name: app1
    image: python:3.7.3-slim
    build: ./APP1/
    volumes:
      - ./APP1/:/usr/src/app/
    environment:
      PORT: 5000
      FLASK_DEBUG: 1
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    tty: true
  neo4:
    container_name: neo4j
    image: neo4j:3.5
    environment:
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=2G
      - dbms_connector_bolt_tls__level=OPTIONAL
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_max__size=3500M
      - NEO4J_AUTH=user/pwd
    volumes:
      - $HOME/neo4j/data:/data
      - $HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs
      - $HOME/neo4j/import:/import
      - $HOME/neo4j/plugins:/plugins
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 7687:7687
```

My `app.py`:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",
            port=5000,
            debug=True
            )
```

And the `Dockerfile` for `APP1`:

```
FROM python:3.7.3-slim
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app/
COPY . /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
EXPOSE 5000
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "app.py"]
```

I then use `docker-compose up` to execute. When I access neo4j through my browser, I can access as normal (http://localhost:7474/) but for the flask app I have no access (http://0.0.0.0:5000/). Where in my configuration am I going wrong?

Comment: You're not going to be able to access anything at `http://0.0.0.0:5000` - that's a non routable address that essentially means "all IPs on the local machine" - in this case, your container. Since your exposing port 5000 on the container to the host machine, you should be able to reach it by going to `http://localhost:5000` (on the host machine running docker) - what happens then?

Comment: @riptusk331 Thank you. With exactly the same settings as my post above, I use http://localhost:5000 and still don't get the page.

Comment: Not what I meant. Keep the `app.run` host to 0.0.0.0 (like in your example) and run the containers. Go to a browser on the computer running docker and try to access `http://localhost:5000` - what happens? Nothing? But you can access `http://localhost:7474`? In that case, then silly question, but when you run `docker ps`, do you see that the `app1` container is up and running? If so, have you checked the logs to see what's going on? If not, then investigate there...

Comment: @riptusk331 I get: "can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:5000" although I can access neo4j (http://localhost:7474). docker ps doesn't show the app. I should note that the docker-compose.yml file resides one folder up from many private pulled git repos. For now I'm just testing the yml with one of these repos. I assume that the image thus container are not made, maybe because of how I have configure the driver in my app: driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri="bolt://neo4j:7687", auth=(id, pwd))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it and it was actually a dumb mistake, but one that could happen to others I guess...
In the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
build: ./APP1/
```

needs to be in quotes, so:

```
build: './APP1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

`http://0.0.0.0:5000` doesn't mean `localhost`, but *all network interfaces*. So you can't reach `localhost`.

Comment: The 0.0.0.0 is a wildcard IP address to match possible incoming ports on the host machine. Port 127.0.0.1 inside a Docker container does not actually get captured and exposed into the host machine...so I read